# How does Codable fit in with iOS restoration process?

Tags: ios, swift, codable, state-restoration

In `AppDelegate.swift` I have:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

And iOS will call my `encodeRestorableState()` & `decodeRestorableState()` class methods during state restoration.

How does `Codable` work with respect to state restoration? What does iOS call and how do I tie in my Codable structs and classes?

Comment: I think you should provide more information to make it more clear...

Answer (score 1):

encodeRestorableState(with:) passes you an instance of NSCoder. Any variables you require to restore your state must be encoded here using encode(_:forKey:) with this coder and must therefore conform to Codable.

decodeRestorableState(with:) passes you this same Coder into the function body. You can access the properties in the decoder with the key you used when they were encoded and then set them to instance variables or otherwise use them to configure your controller.

e.g.

```
import UIKit

struct RestorationModel: Codable {
   static let codingKey = "restorationModel"
   var someStringINeed: String?
   var someFlagINeed: Bool?
   var someCustomThingINeed: CustomThing?
}

struct CustomThing: Codable {
   let someOtherStringINeed = "another string"
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var someStringIDoNotNeed: String?
   var someStringINeed: String?
   var someFlagINeed: Bool?
   var someCustomThingINeed: CustomThing?

   override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
      super.encodeRestorableState(with: coder)
      let restorationModel = RestorationModel(someStringINeed: someStringINeed,
                                              someFlagINeed: someFlagINeed,
                                              someCustomThingINeed: someCustomThingINeed)

      coder.encode(restorationModel, forKey: RestorationModel.codingKey)
   }

   override func decodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
      super.decodeRestorableState(with: coder)
      guard let restorationModel = coder.decodeObject(forKey: RestorationModel.codingKey) as? RestorationModel else {
         return
      }
      someStringINeed = restorationModel.someStringINeed
      someFlagINeed = restorationModel.someFlagINeed
      someCustomThingINeed = restorationModel.someCustomThingINeed
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks. great example for a codable Struct encoded and decoded from a non-codable Class. If your ViewController class was derived from Codable would I simple add additional coder.encode() and coder.decode() calls to encodeRestorableState() and decodeRestorableState() respectively? or would ViewControllers's members be stored "automatically" without the need for specific additions?